# Python error : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python

I have a problem and can't find a solution

```py
while True :
    litres = 29.30 # un litre coûte est 29.01 DZ, Un bon d'un montant de 850 dinars algériens, contenant 29.30 litres
    b=int(input('\n- Entrez le nombre de Bon utilisés en cette mois = '))
    a = b * litres
    print('- Litre utilisés par le voiture est : ',a)
    g=input('- Entrez carburant reste fin de mois précident = ')
    t = a + g
    print('- Carburant totale recus cette mois est : ',t)
```

and this is the error after running the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Katib/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/test3.py", line 11, in <module>
    t = a + g
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It's obvious enough, you are trying to concatenate float and string, `t = str(a) + g` should fix it.

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci I think `t = a + float(g)` will make more sense...

Comment: @DeepSpace, True, but won't throw any error, kekw

Comment: @DeepSpace right, i just glanced at the traceback mb :(

Comment: thank's for your help.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the input function return string, convert it to float, and sum them together.

Try this:

```py
while True :
    litres = 29.30  # un litre coûte est 29.01 DZ, Un bon d'un montant de 850 dinars algériens, 
     # contenant 29.30 litres
     b = int(input('\n- Entrez le nombre de Bon utilisés en cette mois = '))
     a = b * litres
     print('- Litre utilisés par le voiture est : ', a)
     g=float(input('- Entrez carburant reste fin de mois précident = '))
     t = a + g
     print('- Carburant totale recus cette mois est : ', t)
```

Just to make it clear, I'm not a Spanish speaker, but I guess that that's what you meant to (make sense rather than convert `a` to `str` and concatenate them).